# How to suppress a warning on unapproved verbs?

Tags: powershell

When Powershell execute this line:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

I get this warning message :

> WARNING: Some imported command names include unapproved verbs which might make them less discoverable.  Use the Verbose parameter for more detail or type
>       Get-Verb to see the list of approved verbs.

How to suppress this warning?

Comment: If you can use `Import-Module` instead of `Add-PSSnapin`, you can specify `-DisableNameChecking`.

Answer (score 15):

To truly stop getting the name warnings use `-DisableNameChecking`:

```
 import-module MyModule.psm1 -DisableNameChecking
```

Or as mentioned use `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue`:

```
import-module MyModule.psm1 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Or if that doesn't work use the warning stream redirection such as

```
 import-module MyModule.psm1 3>$null
```

*The `3` is not a typo.*

Comment: I wish there was a special variable for this, like `$ConfirmPreference`. For cases where modules are implicitly imported (by just calling the cmdlet `My-Method` directly).

Comment: It's weird that this is an option on the import command. Shouldn't the module author make the decision about the names of their functions, not the module consumer?

Answer (score 2):

You could add it using `-WarningAction SilentlyContinue` like the following:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: No. The warning is still displayed. Thanks.

Comment: This is weird. The SilentlyContinue value should make it ignore any warnings. Additionally, I just tried adding that PSSnapin on a WinServ2008R2 machine with PSv2 (however, it does run Sql Server 2008, not R2) and do not get any such warning (even though the Snapin does register commands with unapproved verbs).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to track down the correct module by adding -DisableNameChecking one-by-one until I found the file.

I had already renamed the function earlier from "Compare-String-Lists" to "Compare-StringLists", but it still gave the warning.
When I renamed that function again from "Compare-StringLists" to "Compare-StrLists" and the warning was gone.

I could then rename it back to "Compare-ListsDifference" and my problem stayed gone.

Comment: Consider updating the original question instead so that people don't try to answer that first without knowing about your progress.